# SAP WEB IDE - How do I include the Mobile Project Type on existing SAPUI5 apps?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

All my new projects (Created with the SAPUI5 Application Template) have a 'Mobile' Project type assigned to them. This allows me to deploy them through the Hybrid App Toolkit.

My existing apps (that I wish to mobilise) don't have this Project type (They only have the SAP Fiori type).

How do I add the Mobile project type for existing SAPUI5 apps?